# bash check for empty string/line using -z

Tags: linux, bash

I am relatively new to bash scripting, and I have the following script, which is not giving me results I expect. So, my script looks like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Today is $(date)"
shopt -s nullglob

FILES=/some/empty/dir/with/no/text/files/*.txt
#echo $FILES


if [ -z "$FILES" ]
then
    echo 'FILES variable is empty'
    exit
else
    echo 'FILES variable is not empty'
    echo 'done' > write_file_out.dat
fi
```

So, the directory I am trying to use `FILES` on is completely empty - and still, when I do `if [ -z "$FILES" ]` it seems to say that it is not empty.

Baffled by this - wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
FILES=/some/empty/dir/with/no/text/files/*.txt
```

You need to use:

```
FILES="$(echo /some/empty/dir/with/no/text/files/*.txt)"
```

Otherwise `$FILES` will be set to: `/some/empty/dir/with/no/text/files/*.txt` and this condition `[ -z "$FILES" ]` will always be false (not empty).

You can also use BASH arrays for shell expansion:

```
FILES=(/some/empty/dir/with/no/text/files/*.txt)
```

And check for:

```
[[ ${#FILES[@]} == 0 ]]
```

for empty check.

Comment: Or `FILES=(/some/empty/dir/with/no/text/files/*.txt)` and then test for an empty array since that is much better to work with when you actually need to do something with the files.

Comment: files will NOT be set to `/some/empty/dir/with/no/text/files/*.txt` because I am using `shopt -s nullglob` You can try using `echo $FILES` to see this

Comment: @AJW: I have used `shopt -s nullglob` but still `FILES=/some/empty/dir/with/no/text/files/*.txt` doesn't make shell expand glob pattern.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Thanks, that was good point, I added it to my answer.

Comment: @AJW, but you were quoting the variable: `[ -z "$FILES" ]` -- that prevents filename expansion. That's also the difference between `echo $FILES` and `echo "$FILES"`. When you declare the variable, filename expansion *does not happen*, not until you **use** the variable.

Comment: thanks a tonne @anubhava - I used your bash arrays for shell expansion (thanks also to @EtanReisner) - and it works perfectly.

Comment: @AJW Globbing never occurs in non-array assignments like this, the expansion of `*` in your example occurs when you do `echo $FILES` without quotes. `$files` _will_ be set to the literal string `/some/empty/dir/with/no/text/files/*.txt`. `nullglob` won't change anything about this fact.

Comment: @anubhava: one problem though - when I do `FILES=(/some/empty/dir/with/no/text/files/*.txt)` and when there are txt files in the directory, it does not seem to show them - well it shows me only 1 file when there are 3 :(

Comment: If you use `echo "${FILES[@]}"` it should show 3 entries.

Comment: thanks @anubhava again - yet another follow up question :( what is the difference between using `"${FILES[@]}"` and just `${FILES[@]}`. I would like to do something with each file using `for f in ${FILES[@]}` but I am not very clear if I should use `for f in "${FILES[@]}"` or `for f in ${FILES[@]}` - although both show me the same results

Comment: You should be using `for f in "${FILES[@]}"` (with quotes) as some filenames can have spaces or newlines.

Comment: Thanks again - you saved so much of my time - REALLY appreciate your help!

Comment: @anubhava: so when I do `[[ ${#FILES[@]} == 0 ]]` I do not need the quotes? i.e not `"${#FILES[@]}"`?

Comment: yes because `${#FILES[@]}` gives a number (i.e. # of entries in array).

Comment: ok - got it - thanks again! Think I have solved it - obviously, with your help :)

Comment: Happy to be a help here. You may accept the answer now :-)

Comment: oh yea - almost forgot about it :) Just accepted your answer - thanks again and have a nice day!